# Windows executeable created with Py2exe won't run on another computer

Tags: python, py2exe

I created an executeable of my Python script. Everything works just fine on my first computer but when  I try to run this very same executeable in another computer, it wont work. When I try to run my executeable I see that computer tries to open it, because command prompt window appears  but nothing else happens, prompt window will disappear. Problem can't be in computer, because both my computers are 32 bit Windows machines and I have done similar things before but this kind of error I see first time.

I don't want to post my code at first, because it is more than 500 lines long. But I will give some more specifications about my problem.

This program I create is actually advanced version of application i made earlier. And earlier version worked fine in both of my computers. This advanced version, I am working on now, is developed into many standalone Python scripts unlike first one which was only one script. Could this be the source of my problem? Should I do something different when running setup.py now when I have many scripts?

And then there is third version of my application. Executeable of it runs fine on computer where I created it, but in my second computer it wont run either. But this time I get error too. When I run this program in my second computer the opening screen of aplication appears, there are some buttons which are meant to open other scripts, when they are clicked on. But when I click them I get following error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

If someone is willing to look into my long code, then I am willing to share it. But again I dont want to post it here.

I am using Python 2.7 and windows 7 in my first computer and windows XP on my second computer.

I would be very grateful if someone points me right direction which helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: Your are probably using some absolute path in your code which doesn't exists at the other pc

Comment: Have you tried opening command prompt and running the file from there? You should see error messages (hopefully) then. Or setup [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) within your application and see where it fails more easily.

Comment: Command prompt is not displaying any errors when I run executeable from command prompt. But same problems remain.

Comment: I removed absolute paths from my code. But application wont still work on my second computer. Now when I click one of the button that should open other script(script2.py), I get following error : `script2.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable progrqam or batch file.` Am I doing the right thing when I make executeble of main page of application using this code:
`# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["C:\Python27\ST2.0_noabsolute\main_page.py"])`